# Who are to be Priest and Levites in Isaiah 66:21?

Tags: isaiah, referent-identification, niv

Isaiah 66:21 NIV

21 And I will select some of them also to be ***priests and Levites***,” says the Lord.

Who are to be selected as Priests and Levites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isaiah 66:21 NIV

> 21 And I will select some of them also to be priests and **Levites**,” says the Lord.

Levites are by definition descendants of Levi. Under this definition, this verse cannot be interpreted literally. Its spiritual significance is that God will select some Gentiles to minister in the services of God's house.

> 1 Peter 2:5
> you also, like living stones, are being built into a spiritual house to be a holy priesthood, offering spiritual sacrifices acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 1):

The NIV Bible mistranslated Isaiah 66:21 [MT] :

> "And from them too will I take for-Kohenim and for-Levites," says YHVH." ( וְגַם־מֵהֶ֥ם אֶקַּ֛ח לַכֹּֽהֲנִ֥ים לַֽלְוִיִּ֖ם אָמַ֥ר יְהֹוָֽה )

Meaning : "All-Your Brothers from-all The-Nations" (כָּל־אֲחֵיכֶ֣ם מִכָּל־הַגּוֹיִ֣ם) will be offered in service **to the Kohenim and to the Levites ( לַכֹּֽהֲנִ֥ים לַֽלְוִיִּ֖ם )** . - Isaiah 66:21 references temple offerings from Isaiah 66:20.